# Git for Windows: get older versions of file?

Tags: git

I am using the great Git for Windows and I want to get old versions of a file. I mean that I want to get the entire file and not just view the code in a preview.

Comment: A useful learning tool for some Windows Users is to use Tortoise Git. Use it as a last resort, but it does work fairly well - in addition it shows you the commands it's using to accomplish a task so you don't have to use Tortoise later. In addition, Tortoise doesn't always use the easiest way to accomplish it, but it's a good way to get in the right path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to just checkout a revision by hash of the file that you want, or the change and go back one.

Use `gitk` to find the hash of the commit that you are interested in.

You can then use `git checkout hashhere`. This will set your whole repository back to that hash.

If all you want is a specific file, use `git checkout hash filepath`.

For example:

```
git checkout 4fda14eefe0388e836aac8feaca68ab18bfad6b1 path/to/file.c
```

If all you want to do is see a file and save it off to somewhere else, `git show` is capable of doing that, `git show hash:filepath` and pipe it out to somewhere you want to save it:

```
git show 4fda14eefe0388e836aac8feaca68ab18bfad6b1:path/to/file.c > savetohere.txt
```

You can also use tree-ish to specify the number of revisions to go back, as well:

```
git show master~2:path/to/file.c > savetohere.txt
```

Which basically says, "2 revisions ago on the master branch, show the path/to/file.c file and pipe the results to savetohere.txt."

Comment: The parameters are flipped, it's "git checkout hash filepath", not "git checkout filepath hash"

Comment: If I checkout a single file, won't that affect my reposity? All i want is a copy of the file x in revision y. Not replace the current revision with the old one.

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout <tree-ish> <path>
```

e.g.

```
git checkout master~2 Makefile
```

Reference: [git checkout man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).